# How can I make the sum of the weights (for the stocks in my portfolio) be equal to 1 while using a genetic algorithm?

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, stock, portfolio, genetic-programming

I am running a genetic algorithm in R, to select weights for the stocks in a portfolio while having the highest return/risk ratio. The problem is that weights need to sum up to 1 but the code that I have tried so far doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
normalise=function(v){v/sum(v)}
f=function(weights){
  weights=normalise(weights)
  (weights%*%returns)/(weights%*%variances)

}
GA=ga(type="real",fitness=f,lower=rep(0,length(positive)),
      upper=rep(1,length(positive)),maxiter=20000,run=300)
```

Comment: Provide a small, reproducible dataset so we can get some context to your problem.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for instructions on how to create a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you do not actually "repair" the solution: you only map it to a feasible one before you evaluate it. Which is something you may actually do; but then you must map the solution of the GA as well, i.e. normalise the weights that the GA returns. (See for instance [Maringer, D. and Oyewumi, O. (2007). Index Tracking with Constrained Portfolios](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/isaf.285).)

Comment: Ok I understand. So you mean that weights should also be normalised outside the GA. I used both the approaches separately. But wouldn't that make the normalisation inside the GA (the code above) redundant?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. You want the GA to find a solution that looks good when normalised, so you need to pass such a solution to the objective function. Otherwise, the objective function may lead to a solution that looks bad when normalised.